# Cannot update GITHUB_PATH in Github Actions

Tags: github-actions

I tried different suggestions to update GITHUB_PATH with no success:

```
name: learn-github-actions
run-name: ${{ github.actor }} is learning GitHub Actions
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  check-bats-version:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        architecture: [x64]
    steps:
      - name: Check GITHUB_PATH
        run: echo "FIRST:$GITHUB_PATH"  # <--- No value

      - name: Install WiX 3.11
        run: |
          mkdir D:\wix311
          Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/releases/download/wix3111rtm/wix311-binaries.zip' -OutFile 'wix311-binaries.zip'
          Expand-Archive -Path 'wix311-binaries.zip' -DestinationPath 'D:\wix311'
          dir "D:\wix311" # <-- Verified candle.exe exists              
          echo "D:\wix311" >> $GITHUB_PATH  
          candle.exe  # <--- Error (command not found)           
        shell: powershell
        
      - name: Check GITHUB_PATH 2
        run: echo "NEXT:$GITHUB_PATH"   # <--- No value
```

I also tried these with no luck:

```
# echo "D:\wix311" >> $env:GITHUB_PATH
# Add-Content -Path $env:GITHUB_PATH -Value ";D:\wix311"
```

Any clues what I am missing please?

Comment: Have you tried `echo $env:GITHUB_PATH`?

Comment: Try what's been mentioned in the official docs: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions?tool=powershell#adding-a-system-path.

Comment: @Azeem it worked. Wanna add an answer so I can mark it as correct? Thanks.